# I need help identifying group of table members that have different status in another table

Tags: t-sql

I wasn't able to google my way to figuring this out. I'm still very new to TSQL and I thought I could solve this with a self joins and sub queries. But I'm getting to many results and don't know how to tame them. I appreciate the help. It's nice to see all the different methods people suggest for the same problem. I know I get tunnel vision when trying to solve a problem, when it's better to try it from a different angle.

My goal is this. I want to Return the HouseholdID of all Households whose PersonID's HairColor don't all match each other. Whatever the color may be. So below HouseHoldID 200 would return since their PersonID's HairColor differ from each other. Unlike HouseHoldID 300 whose PersonID's HairColor do match each other.

```
               HouseholdMember
+------------+-----------------+-----------+
| MemberID   |   HouseholdID   | PersonID  |
+------------+-----------------+-----------+
|    100     |       200       |     1     |
|    101     |       200       |     2     |
|    102     |       200       |     3     |
|    103     |       300       |     4     |
|    104     |       300       |     5     |
|    105     |       300       |     6     |
+------------+-----------------+-----------+

                    Person
+------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+
|  PersonID  |    FirstName    | LastName  |  HairColor |
+------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+
|     1      |      Josh       |   Smith   |    Brown   |
|     2      |      Jerry      |   Smith   |    Black   |
|     3      |      Ethan      |   Smith   |    Red     |
|     4      |      Mike       |   Jones   |    Black   |
|     5      |      Devan      |   Jones   |    Black   |
|     6      |      Todd       |   Jones   |    Black   |
+------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+

                     Household
+---------------+-----------------+----------------+
|  HouseholdID  |      Name       |    Address     |
+---------------+-----------------+----------------+
|      200      |      Smith's    | 123 Candy Dr   |
|      300      |      Jones's    | 812 Dentist Ln |
+---------------+-----------------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option uses aggregation:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT hm.HouseholdID
    FROM HouseholdMember hm
    INNER JOIN Person p ON hm.PersonID = p.PersonID
    GROUP BY hm.HouseholdID
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT p.HairColor) > 1
)

SELECT *
FROM Household
WHERE HouseholdID IN (SELECT HouseholdID FROM cte);
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: Wow thanks. I've seen CTE before but never used it. Time to drill on that. Other than Youtube. Do you have any recommendations for learning more. There's just so many different books, and I do use udemy.com but again so many choices.

Comment: I got good at SQL by using it at work and also by spending time on Stack Overflow.  Technical skills aren't much different from any other skill (e.g music, sports, etc.); practice makes perfect, and you will get good at SQL if you use it a lot.

Comment: needs a `NOT` before the last `IN`, since we want the households that *aren't* mono-coloured... ("So below HouseHoldID 200 would return since their PersonID's HairColor differ from each other. Unlike HouseHoldID 300 whose PersonID's HairColor do match each other.")

Comment: @AakashM You're right.  We can just assert that the distinct hair color count is _greater_ than one in this case.